# How to get cat allergens out of a furnished apartment

Tags: cats, cleaning, allergies

Take the following scenario: the tenant of a completely furnished apartment (including bed linen and towels) keeps a cat (European Shorthair) in there. The cat roams outside a lot of the time, but he also spends a significant amount of time inside, leaving hair and other things which can cause reactions in people who are allergic to cats.

Now suppose the tenant moves out (with the cat), and 1–2 days later a new tenant with a cat allergy moves in.

What would need to be done in the apartment (beyond regular cleaning) to get all cat allergens out, so the new tenant will not have any issues?

The floors in the apartment are hardwood and tiles, with carpets placed on top in a few spots. There is some upholstered furniture (part leather, part fabric) in there, as well as curtains.

Answer (score 4):

You need to start by vacuuming any soft surfaces like fabric, carpets, curtains (use a vacuum with a HEPA filter); you might want to leave the windows open to get clean air inside and to get the dust out while vacuuming.

Any textiles that you can remove from the apartment need to be washed and dried before you put them back.

Next you need to wash all of the hard surfaces with soap and water and change water often, it is best to start washing on top of each room and work your way down to the floor.

Clean one room at the time, start with the room farthest from the entrance; when you have cleaned each room, close the doors (if possible); this is to avoid contaminating the cleaned rooms with allergens when you move around in the apartment.